# How do I run private modules on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I have an application that I'd like to split into three layers:

1. Public facing web service
2. Private web service
3. Private data store

1) are stateless frontend web servers that renders UI and mostly acts as proxy for 2).

2) must only be accessible from 1) and **not** the public internet.

3) must only be accessible from 2) and **not** 1) or the public internet.

I'd like to use GAE managed VMs for deploying both 1) and 2), while 3) is deployed to GCE. It's clear to me how to tag instances in GCE such that I can create firewall rules that apply to 3). However, it's not clear to me how to tag 1) and 2). I've looked into whatever documentation I can find on app.yaml and other things, but there doesn't seem to be much to find on instance tagging.

Is it possible to automatically tag GAE instances, and if so how?

Comment: Have you looked at filtering requests coming into 2) and 3) with the ```X-AppEngine-Inbound-AppId```  header? Google will automatically add that header to any request made by another google app engine instance. any external requests that contain that header will be filtered long before they get your application.

Comment: I didn't know about this header, do you know where I can read more offical docs on it? A cursory search didn't produce much of any use, although from forum posts and the likes it looks like this is the conventional wisdom to resolve this.

It'd work for 1) talking to 2), but not 2) talking to 3) because it's not over HTTP, so I'd need something lower level. I should've added this to the question, I'll update it.

Comment: Also this puts a lot of onus on the application developer to get things right, which I suppose isn't that much to ask but I'd also like to firewall 2) so it's never reachable from the public internet, only from instances of 1).

Comment: More info on the X-AppEngine-Inbound-AppId header is available at: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/