# How should I create a Google App Engine service visible only within my project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

I'd like to create a Google App Engine service to use as a microservice. I'd like its API to only be accessible to callers within my project's network (i.e., from the Google Compute Engine and GAE instances on my project). What's the easiest way to restrict access like this?

I see from [How do I run private modules on Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632756/how-do-i-run-private-modules-on-google-app-engine) that a check for `X-AppEngine-Inbound-AppId` works for requests from GAE, but this doesn't help for requests from GCE.

To restrict a GCE service I would use Networking. I don't think GAE instances can be assigned to networks though.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `X-AppEngine-Inbound-AppId` matches your app id.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/

Appengine identity api doc contains using `X-AppEngine-Inbound-AppId` for asserting identity.

```
import webapp2


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     allowed_app_ids = [
        'other-app-id',
        'other-app-id-2'
    ]

    def get(self):
        incoming_app_id = self.request.headers.get(
            'X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid', None)

        if incoming_app_id not in self.allowed_app_ids:
            self.abort(403)

        self.response.write('This is a protected page.')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: This only works if requests from Google Compute Engine set the `X-AppEngine-Inbound-AppId` header. I was under the impression they didn't. Do they?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I can't understand what I had read. You can use jwt (json web token) for server to server authentication. See `Asserting identity to third-party services` section in that documentation.

Comment: The method described in that documentation under that section seems to require `google.appengine.api` in order to sign messages, which isn't accessible in GCE without remote_api, which I can't use in some of my relevant scripts.